# UMN MapServer alternatives

Tags: open-source-gis, mapserver, software-recommendations

I am new to GIS application world. I would like to ask what are the other alternatives to [**UMN MapServer**](http://mapserver.org/)  in the market preferably open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) probably is the most known option among the open-source feature server applications. However, I personally use MapServer.

Here you can check some info about both applications:

1. http://www.slideshare.net/ssuser185516/mapserver-vs-geoserver-16107836
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670361/mapserver-vs-geoserver
3. http://anitagraser.com/2010/06/08/geoserver-vs-mapserver/

To answer your second question (about commercial GIS apps), the "Mercedes Benz" of the GIS applications is [ArcGis](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis) (based on some lists such as http://www.gisdoctor.com/site/gis-help/commercial-gis-software/).

However, I think you can achieve lot of GIS capabilities with two open-source software projects, these are:

1. [QGis](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/)
2. [GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/)

Wikipedia is a good source to search for more open-source and commercial applications: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. it helped me a lot

Comment: @Grey I would  like aslo to ask if you know some commercial GIS application similar to GeoServer and MapServer ??

Comment: @basheer you're welcome, please refer to my above answer about your 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

[MapGuide opensource](https://mapguide.osgeo.org/) is, like MapServer, a cartographic engine server-side.